# Sorting elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of nodes that I'm able to drag and drop.

```
<ul id="container">
<li id="item_1">Item 1</li>
<li id="item_2">Item 2</li>
<li id="item_3">Item 3</li>
<li id="item_4">Item 4</li>
<li id="item_5">Item 5</li>
<li id="item_6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I can click and drag #item_5 over on top of #item_2 and on "drop", 
I can return the source (#item_5) and the item getting dropped on (#item2)

**How would I insert the dropped item (#item_5) before the target (#item_2), then 
adjust each node after Item 2 back one position?** I need help with a method to perform this task

e.g.

```
function movebefore(a, b) {...}
```

(Please assume javascript frameworks like jQuery *cannot* be used)

The actual code:
http://jsfiddle.net/danmasq/BkNAF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function movebefore(a, b) { // If "a" is the node you're dragging and "b" is the node on top of which you dropped "a"
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b); // Or "b.nextSibling", depending on what you want to do
}
```

It's that simple!  The DOM will take care of removing the element from its previous position and adjusting the other elements.

Answer (score 2):

dropNode is the drop target
dragNode is the node being dragged
you mentioned you had both available.

```
var movebefore = function( dragNode , dropNode ) {

    dropNode.parentNode.insertBefore( dragNode , dropNode );

}
```